# Find running total as value changes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to get a running total as value changes. my table has sequence of values and they keep changing. I need to give output as how many times the value repeated in a sequence.

For ex: lets say table has two values.

```
abc 0
abc 0
abc 1
abc 0
abc 0
abc 0
abc 1
abc 1
abc 0
def 1
def 1
def 0
def 1
def 0
```

I know we need to use row_number and lag functions but unable to determine when exactly sequence changes.

and I want to end result as

```
abc 0   1
abc 0   2
abc 1   1
abc 0   1
abc 0   2
abc 0   3
abc 1   1
abc 1   2
abc 0   1
def 1   1
def 1   2
def 0   1
def 1   1
def 0   1
```

Comment: Formatting issues. Below is the table creation and insert stmts. Sorry. 

create table tt (id text, value int);

insert into tt values ('abc',0),('abc',0), ('abc',1), ('abc',0), ('abc',0), ('abc',0), ('abc',1), ('abc',1), ('abc',0), ('def',1), ('def',1), ('def',0), ('def',1), ('def',0);

Comment: That should go in your question, not a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, you can do what you want -- assuming that you have a column specifying the ordering.  Such a column might be a `serial` column or insertion date/time or something else.

With such a column this is a gaps and islands problem.  I think the simplest solution is to use the difference of row numbers to identify the groups:

```
select col1, col2,
       row_number() over (partition by col1, col2, (seqnum - seqnum_2) order by <ordering column>) as col3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col1 order by <ordering column>) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by <ordering column>) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon.. My problem was something similar and thanks for the hint on gaps and islands.. I was able to solve my issue.. Your hint helped me in resolving my issue. Appreciate your help.